# How can i dynamically change colors of the table prototype cell labels in the interval

Tags: ios, swift, dynamic, intervals

i have been searching a logic to dynamically change colors of labels in the tableView , i am using an arrayList to print subjects (hindi,english,maths,punjabi, geography) printed on the tabels prototype cell , now i want to change colors of all the subjects in the interval of every three , like first cell label should be red, second should be green , and third should be white , and follow this dynamic rule for furthur cells

here is the method i used to print static cell label colors

```
    switch subjectsList[indexPath.row] {
    case subjectsList[1],subjectsList[4]:
        cell.subjectFirstLetter.textColor = UIColor.orange
    case subjectsList[2],subjectsList[5]:
        cell.subjectFirstLetter.textColor = UIColor.red
    default:
        cell.subjectFirstLetter.textColor = UIColor.white
    }
```

how can i make this dynamic ?

Update :- solved

```
let remainder = indexPath.row % 3
switch remainder {
case 1:
    cell.subjectFirstLetter.textColor = .orange
case 2:
    cell.subjectFirstLetter.textColor = .red
default: // e.g. zero
    cell.subjectFirstLetter.textColor = .white
}
```

Comment: Just refer this -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic

Answer (score 3):

Use `Modulo`:

```
let color: UIColor

switch indexPath.row % 3 {
case 0:
    color = UIColor.red
case 1:
    color = UIColor.green
case 2:
    color = UIColor.white
default:
    break
}

cell.subjectFirstLetter.textColor = color
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the modulo (remainder) operator here with the indexPath to set the label color:

```
let remainder = indexPath.row % 3
switch remainder {
case 1:
    cell.subjectFirstLetter.textColor = .orange
case 2:
    cell.subjectFirstLetter.textColor = .red
default: // e.g. zero
    cell.subjectFirstLetter.textColor = .white
}
```

(Note that you can use the shortcut for accessing UIColor here.)

Comment: Thanx Sir , problem solved and understood the logic now .